# How can i call class from aspx file?

Tags: asp.net

i have a class which is in App_Code/Kerbooo.cs 
i want to call that class's method from aspx file (not from code behind) 
is it possible? if it is, how can i do?  
thank you very much already now.

Answer (score 1):

If the method is static, then the following should work within the aspx page:

```
<% Kerbooo.Method1(...) %>
```

If the method is not static, then you'll need an instance of Kerbooo:

```
<%
var kerbooo = new Kerbooo();
kerbooo.Method1(...)
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, import the namespace that your code in App_Code uses:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="MyNamespace" %>
```

If your code isn't in a namespace yet, it's a good idea to put it in one.

Next, you can call your code either with `<% code; %>` or `<%= code %>`, depending on whether you want to write the results to the output stream or not.

Data binding, as in `<%# %>`, requires a little extra work, as do expressions in `<%$ %>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use <% %> and put your code in between (if you want to write stuff out <%= %> is a short cut for response.write but you need to do this outside of the <% %>

```
<%
 var bob = new Kerbooo();
..do stuff with class
%>
```

you can mix and match (this does lead to spaghetti code so be carefull)
e.g looping

```
<table>
 <%
     var bob = new Kerbooo();
     foreach(var thing in bob.GetThings())
{
 %>
<tr><td><%=thing.StuffToWrite%><td></tr>
<%}%>
</table>
```

Comment: When i use that in gridview i get error. i try to use that like that <% Kerberos kerbooo = new Kerberos(); %> <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#kerbooo.MethodNameEval("DBValue").ToString()) %>'></asp:Label>

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: i am getting value from database into to gridview. but incoming value is 0 or 1. i try to translate this numbers values to readable values like day name with this method.

Comment: The gridview and the label in your comment are both server side controls, binding data to a gridview is a little more complex, setting the text of a label programmtically can be done in the code behind or (if as you say you dont want to use code behind) use a server script tag on overload the page_load event, i added an example from wikiperdia for this.

Comment: actually, scratch my last comment, it looks like what you have done is bound a gridview with a label as part of the template and you need to call a helper method on your kerbooo object to populate the value based on the databound value, am I close?

Comment: When i call this method from aspx file's (default.aspx) code behind file (default.aspx.cs), i don't get error. but i want to use method from app_code/kerbooo.cs for using in my other aspx page. that label which i wrote in my past comment, it is in gridview.

Comment: so sametime, if i register kerbooo class in code behind, i can call a public method from app_code/kerbooo.cs like that: "kerbooo kerbooo = new kerbooo(); kerbooo.MethhodName();" clearly i want to this in aspx file's gridview object.

Answer (score 0):

And your method should be public if your aspx does not inherit from a class in codebehind